# Problem with .collect() method in list .stream() in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, java-stream, collectors

```
public class PositiveNumbers {
    public static List<Integer> positive(List<Integer> numbers){

        return numbers.stream()
                .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                .filter(s -> s >= 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList<Integer>::new));
    }
}
```

[Image of the code and description of problem given by IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc5qz.png)

Tried all that program gives as fix, asked chatGPT, but no results. I cannot see the problem.

I tried also

```
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but same problem...

Comment: Habe you taken a look at the [definition of `IntStream::collect` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer))? The method takes three parameters.

Comment: `.boxed().toList();` or since you're already dealing with an Integer Stream, simply `return numbers.stream().filter(s -> s >= 0).toList();`

Comment: Forgot to write which one. Its Java 19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `mapToInt()` without any reason, you can do this way:

```java
public static List<Integer> positive(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return numbers.stream()
                  .filter(s -> s >= 0)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can also, replace `.collect(Collectors.toList())` with [`.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()), which is available **since java 16**.